# Hadoop Custom Java Program

Tags: hadoop, jar, classnotfoundexception

I have a simple java program called putmerge that I am trying to execute. I have been at it for like 6hrs, researched many places on the web but could not find solution. Basically I try to build the jar with all class libraries with the following command:

```
javac -classpath *:lib/* -d playground/classes playground/src/PutMerge.java
```

And then I build the jar with the following command.

```
jar -cvf playground/putmerge.jar -C playground/classes/ .
```

And then I try to execute it with the following command:

```
bin/hadoop jar playground/putmerge.jar org.scd.putmerge "..inputPath.." "..outPath"
```

..

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.scd.putmerge
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153)
```

I tried every permutation/combination to run this simple jar, however I always get some kind of exception as shown above.

My source code:

```
package org.scd.putmerge;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

/**
 * 
 * @author Anup V. Saumithri
 *
 */
public class PutMerge
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
        {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf); 
        FileSystem local = FileSystem.getLocal(conf);

        Path inputDir = new Path(args[0]);
        Path hdfsFile = new Path(args[1]);



        try
        {
            FileStatus[] inputFiles = local.listStatus(inputDir);
            FSDataOutputStream out = hdfs.create(hdfsFile);

            for(int i=0; i<inputFiles.length; i++)
            {
                System.out.println(inputFiles[i].getPath().getName());
                FSDataInputStream in = local.open(inputFiles[i].getPath());

                byte buffer[] = new byte[256];
                int bytesRead = 0;
                while((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
                {
                    out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                in.close();
            }
            out.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are putting your PutMerge class inside the jar may be a little incorrect.

If you do a `jar tf putmerge.jar`, you must see the PutMerge class inside the path mentioned in your package (org.scd.putmerge) in your code (i.e. org/scd/putmerge).

If not try doing the following to achieve that. Make sure you have copied PutMerge.class inside org/scd/putmerge/ directory.

```
jar -cvf playground/putmerge.jar org/scd/putmerge/PutMerge.class
```

Next, verify again with `jar tf putmerge.jar` to check if now see `org/scd/putmerge/PutMerge.clas`s in the output.

If everything's fine, you can try to run the hadoop jar again. But looking at the errors, I see that you haven't actually included the PutMerge class with the package. You should use **org.scd.putmerge.PutMerge**. So, the correct way should be something like --

```
bin/hadoop jar playground/putmerge.jar org.scd.putmerge.PutMerge "..inputPath.." "..outPath"
```

Comment: Brilliant! That solved my problem. Thanks a ton. For the records the issue was with my package specification inside of bin/hadoop jar command. I changed it to org.scd.putmerge.PutMerge as you have mentioned above...... and it started working....